# Merging sheets and keeping non-null values

Tags: microsoft-excel

This probably has a very simple solution, I just don't know what search terms to use.

I have several different Excel workbooks. They all have a sheet with the same information, some of which is the same, and some of which is only non-null in one of the workbooks. Something like this:

Workbook 1:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo |  |
| 2 | Bar | 2 |
| 3 | Baz |  |

Workbook 2:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 4 |
| 2 | Bar |  |
| 3 | Baz | 9 |

Just with a lot more workbooks. However, the "Value" field is only populated in one workbook for each row. In all the rest of the workbooks, it's null.

Now I need to merge them into this:

| ID | Name | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 4 |
| 2 | Bar | 2 |
| 3 | Baz | 9 |

I have created data queries with each separate workbook as a source, based on the ID field, but when I merge the queries, it only takes the values from the first workbook. The rest are null.

How do I merge the "Value" columns, by keeping all the non-null values from all workbooks/queries?

Comment: yes lots of ways to do it. Assuming no data integrity issues, and depending on the need for repeatability 1) just copy/paste, then filter/delete all null values, 2) write a formula, 3) use power Query, 4) use VBA. 2-4 are basically automation of 1)...

Comment: When working with multiple files I'd usually recommend vba, references are possible as well if your file location, filename and sheet names are not changing.

Comment: import several Excel files located in the same folder with [PowerQuery](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE)),VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$B$2:$C$4,2,FALSE))
```

[image]